# calculate the number of simultaneous Passenger instances

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I need to find out if a server I have is capable of handling a number of traffic. I'm running ruby on rails with passenger and apache.

So let say on average a page takes 2 seconds to render and their will be 200k visitors in a day. The busiest hour will see 300 page views in a minute. From this how can I work out how many simultaneous Passenger instances I'll need to handle the expected load and then from that how much RAM I'll need to handle the required number of Passenger processes.

Hopefully this will tell me what server(s) I'll need and maybe a load balancer(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to know for sure is to simulate the load with a benchmarking tool. Memory usage is highly application specific, and can even depend on the areas of the application you're exercising, so if you can generate reasonable diversity in your test data you'll have a much better idea of how it scales.

For a rough start try the `ab` tool that comes with Apache. For something more complete, there are a number of simulation systems that will perform a series of events like logging in, viewing pages, and so on, like [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/).

Comment: The 'ab' tool from Apache really helped me out when I could  understand what it's showing me. Thanks!